# Proving that a metric space of all real valued continuous functions is complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, intuition

Let $X$ be a compact space and $A \subset X$ be a closed subspace. Then we define  $C_{\mathbb{R}}(A)$ to be the set of all continuous functions $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose we have a metric $d : C_{\mathbb{R}}(A) \times C_{\mathbb{R}}(A) \to \mathbb{R}$. Then I have been tasked with showing that all Cauchy-sequences in the metric space $(C_{\mathbb{R}}(A), d)$ converge.

I feel quite insecure in topology, but my idea was to show that if a Cauchy-sequence $(f_n)$ converges to a function $f$, then $f$ is also continuous. I would use the definition "$f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $A$ if for all open sets $O \in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $A$. This is where I need corrections, so please shoot down my claims if they are not true:

1. This requires for $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$ to have topologies. $A$ being compact, it already has a topology, call it $T$, and for $\mathbb{R}$ we may just use the *order topology*
2. Continuity of $f$ depends on the topologies defined on $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$. It is, however, sufficient to prove continuity of $f$ using just the topologies picked in $1)$, since then it would also hold for arbitrary topologies

Especially $2)$ is what I'm in doubt of. If it turns out to hold, then I would appreciate it if you would take the time to formulate an explanation as to why. Thank you very much. Regards, kasp9201.

Comment: An arbitrary metric on $C_{\mathbb R} (A)$ need not be complete. Where did you find this question?

Comment: Hi Kavi, my apologies. I was given a concrete metric on $C_\mathbb{R}(A)$, but I did not include it. I realize now that either I should have, or I should have explained why I withheld it. Anyways, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set-up is a bit vague, but I'll give it a shot:

Showing that all $d$-Cauchy sequences converge (under $d$ of course) entails
that we start with a sequence of $(f_n)$ of functions from $C_{\mathbb{R}}(A)$, so all $f_n : A \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous (in the subspace topology of $A$ w.r.t. $X$, and the reals in the standard/order topology), and from Cauchyness somehow (most of the time in such situations we have pointwise Cauchyness and we use completeness of the reals) produce an $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ which must also be shown to be in $C_{\mathbb{R}}(A)$, so continuous too, and show that $d(f_n,f) \to 0$. There are no arbitary topologies here: $A$ has a given topology from being a subset of $X$ (which implicitly has a topology as you call $X$ compact), the reals always have their standard topology unless explicitly stated otherwise etc. Cauchy and convergence must be meant under $d$ (that's what completeness in a metric means).

So you must produce a candidate limit which you must prove to be in the space $C_{\mathbb{R}}(A)$, hence continuous.

We could help you better if things were more concrete and explicit.

Comment: Hi Henno, thank you very much for you explanation. This gave me exactly what I needed. Also, I apologize for the vague explanation. Of course I was given a concrete metric, but I did not present it here. I realize now that I should have explained why in my initial question. What I actually needed was just some intuition on the topologies of $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$ so that I could solve the question myself. You exactly gave me this, so thanks. I'll therefore accept this as an answer. Thank you very much

Comment: @kasp9201 Glad I did help a bit.